# js link for Scrolling to a div but keeping a padding on the top of the div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am using links of divs on my side navbar to scroll to the div on click.but for my fixed top header.the upper part of the div is getting hidden when it come to the div using js scroll.
so I need to give a padding on the top of div so div does not get hidden.

side navbar link here:

```html
<a href="#" id="connection_button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Connection Details</a>
```

main div here:

```html
<div id="connection">
  @include('/connection_table/connection')
</div>
```

here is my js part.

```
$("#connection_button").click(function() {
  $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#connection").offset().top},
  'slow');
});
```

so when I it scroll to the connection div ,the upper part of the connection div is get overlapped by the top fixed header.so how to give a padding on scroll?

Comment: Have you thought about calculating your header `.height()` and adding that value to the offset top ?

Comment: no.how to calculate?

Comment: as there is some db table in the page so the height will not always remain same

Comment: `$("#connection").offset().top - $('header').height()`

Comment: thank u @RokoC.Buljan